# Initialize reference member of base class

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class

after a long period of abstinence, I'm currently trying to refresh my C++ skills. Therefore I am implementing a tiny drawing-circles-on-images program.

The scenario:
I've got a base class called **Shape**, which essentially consists of a single member which is a reference to a **Point** denoting the center. A **Circle** is a **Shape** which - in addition to the center - has a radius.

```
class Shape
{

public:
    Shape(Point& p);
    ~Shape();
    Point& get_center() const;

private:
    Point& center;
};
```

-

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point();
    Point(float x, float y);
    Point(short d);
    ~Point();
    float get_x() const;
    float get_y() const;
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Point& p);

private:
    short dimension;
    float x, y;
};

//.cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const Point &p) {
    return strm << "Point(" << p.get_x() << "," << p.get_y() << ")";
}
```

-

```
class Circle :
    public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(Point p);
    Circle(Point p, float radius);
    ~Circle();
    float get_radius() const;

private:
    float radius;
    typedef Shape super;
};
```

The initialization of the members is performed as follows:

```
Circle::Circle(Point p, float rad) : Shape(p), radius(rad)
{
    std::cout << "Called circle constructor with center point " << p << std::endl;
}

Shape::Shape(Point& p) : center(p) {
    std::cout << "Called Shape constructor with point " << p << "a" <<std::endl;
}
```

If I am then running the following code, it seems like the center variable is not properly set, resulting in Output A given below. Strangely, if I append some more output to the **Shape** constructor (in this example the letter "a"), the reference to the center **Point** seems to be set (Output B). Furthermore, both **Circle**s seem to reference the same **Point**?! Can somebody explain why this is happening, and what would be the appropriate way to handle such a scenario?

```
Circle& cir1 = *(new Circle(Point(400, 550), 50));
Circle& cir2 = *(new Circle(Point(300, 550), 80));

vector<Circle> circles { cir1, cir2 };

cout << "Iterating circles" << endl;
for (auto& cir : circles)
{
    cout << "Radius: "<< cir.get_radius() << " center: " << cir.get_center() << endl;
}
```

Output A:

```
Called Shape constructor with point Point(400,550)
Called circle constructor with center point Point(400,550)
Called Shape constructor with point Point(300,550)
Called circle constructor with center point Point(300,550)
Iterating circles
Radius: 50 center: Point(1.87436e-38,1.87419e-38)
Radius: 80 center: Point(1.87436e-38,1.87419e-38)
```

Output B:

```
Called Shape constructor with point Point(400,550)a
Called circle constructor with center point Point(400,550)
Called Shape constructor with point Point(300,550)a
Called circle constructor with center point Point(300,550)
Iterating circles
Radius: 50 center: Point(300,550)
Radius: 80 center: Point(300,550)
```

Comment: This would be a simpler way to create `Circle` objects and avoid memory leaks `Circle cir1(Point(400, 550), 50); Circle cir2(Point(300, 550), 80);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem here:

```
Circle::Circle(Point p, float rad) : Shape(p), radius(rad)

{
    std::cout << "Called circle constructor with center point " << p << std::endl;
}

Shape::Shape(Point& p) : center(p) {
    std::cout << "Called Shape constructor with point " << p << "a" <<std::endl;
}
```

because the `Shape` stores a reference to the `p` parameter of `Circle`. At the end of the construction, the parameter goes away.

I would probably not store a reference, but a value. That way you have a copy of the parameter. Copying a `Point` is not very expensive.

Comment: argh.  obvious now, how did I miss that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A proper interface of your Shape class might look like this:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    explicit Shape(const Point& p); //const Point& ensures you can all that constructor with an R-value
    virtual ~Shape();

    const Point& get_center() const;
private:
    Point center;

};
```

Similary, your Circle class should also take const Point& in the constructor.

Regarding your main program, maybe do something like this

```
std::shared_ptr<Circle> cir1(new Circle(Point(400, 550), 50));
std::shared_ptr<Circle> cir2( new Circle(Point(300, 550), 80));

vector< std::shared_ptr<Circle> > circles { cir1, cir2 };

cout << "Iterating circles" << endl;
for (auto cir : circles)
{
    cout << "Radius: "<< cir->get_radius() << " center: " << cir->get_center() << endl;
}
```

The problem about your code is that you are taking the reference of an R-value (e.g. see http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c ). Hope that helps.